# Python: Global variable can only be parsed but not updated

Tags: python, concurrency, multiprocessing, global-variables

According to a lot of other posts concerning about modification of global variable in Python, I used global keyword. However, in find_new(), I can only successfully parse result from global but I can not change its value to global. The print result in the code never has the same value. Same thing happened to all other global declaration variables. I tried to monitor the file change under a directory every 5 seconds and reflect the change as a list to the global so I can use it for other process. Any way to fix this?

My code:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
from multiprocessing import Process
from threading import Thread 

import os
import time

def find_new():
    global result
    global new_in
    while(1):
        result_next = [os.path.join(dp, f) for dp, dn, filenames in os.walk(mypath) for f in filenames]
        new_in.extend([x for x in result_next if x not in result])
        result = result_next
        print result
        time.sleep(5)
....

if __name__== '__main__':
    #mypath = "/bj_truenas/bbr_rsync/us2bj"
    mypath = "/home/shiweizhou/proj0.1/Source"
    result = [os.path.join(dp, f) for dp, dn, filenames in os.walk(mypath) for f in filenames]
    new_in=[]
    print "before concurrency"
    Process(target=find_new).start()
    Process(target=check_exist).start()
    print "after concurrency"
    while(1):
        print result
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: You have different processes that aren't sharing state.

Comment: Processes don't have access to each other's variables. They get independent copies, and sometimes not even that. (The API mimics `threading` so closely, and the docs do almost nothing to explain the crucial differences, so people keep getting led into this trap.)

Comment: Thx for the above comment. Threading perfectly solves this problem and global variable can be shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're starting two separate processes and hoping to share global variables between the processes.

This simply won't work. The two processes can't share data without some explicit communication mechanism between them.